# Matching strings to values in a different data frame

Tags: r

Consider this data frame, containing multiple entries for a person named Steve/Stephan Jones and a person named Steve/Steven Smith (as well as Jane Jones and Matt/Matthew Smith)

```
df <- data.frame(First = c("Steve", "Stephan", "Steve", "Jane", "Steve", "Steven", "Matt"),
                 Last = c(rep("Jones", 4), rep("Smith", 3)))
```

What I'd like is to match values of `First` to the appropriate value of `Name` in this data frame.

```
nicknames <- data.frame(Name = c("Stephan", "Steven", "Stephen", "Matthew"),
                       N1 = c(rep("Steve", 3), "Matt"))
```

To yield this target

```
target <- data.frame(First = c("Stephan", "Stephan", "Stephan", "Jane", "Steven", "Steven", "Matthew"),
                     Last = c(rep("Jones", 4), rep("Smith", 3)))
```

The issue is that there are multiple values of `Name` corresponding to a `N1` (or `First`) value of `"Steve"`, so I need to check within each group based of `df$Last` to see which version of Steven/Stephan/Stephen is correct.

Using something like this

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  group_by(Last) %>% 
  mutate(First = First[which.max(str_length(First))])
```

won't work because the value of `"Jane"` in row 4 will be converted to `"Stephan"`

Comment: I don't understand your algorithm: How do you choose the right nickname to the right name?

Comment: That's the core issue.  The df contains multiple entries for a person named Steve/Stephan Jones and a person named Steve/Steven Smith (as well as Jane Jones and Matt/Matthew Smith).  What I'm asking about is how to match Stephan to to Steve Jones and Steven to Steve Smith.

Comment: Hello, and apologies in advance for any confusion over `@Greg`! Just checking: what constitutes the "default" first name for a person?  Is it simply the the longest of the eligible first names for each person? You imply this by `which.max(str_length(First))`, yet since `"Stephan"` and `"Stephen"` are of the same length, and since `which.max` defaults to the earliest `max`, then results will vary by sorting. So if we are applying the inverse of some `as_nickname()` function to `"Steve"` | `"Jones"`, how are we to choose between the first names `"Stephan"`, `"Steven"`, and `"Stephen"`?

Comment: @Greg - the "default" first name for each person is the longest (i.e. non-nickname) version of their name listed from them in `df`.  So `"Steve"` Jones is also listed as `"Stephan"` Jones in `df`.  There is an assumption being made here that there's only one Steve/Stephan Jones and not (for example) two people, one named Stephan Jones and the other Stephen Jones.

Comment: Gotcha.  Might there ever be two separate people in `df`, named (say) `"Stephan"` `"Jones"` and `"Steven"` `"Jones"`, who might or might not correspond (ambiguously) to another `"Steve"` `"Jones"` in the same `df`?  The challenge is that these `nicknames` do not provide a one-to-one mapping, so the inverse of this mapping is ambiguous...

Comment: Let's say no, just because I think that circumstance would not be solvable (although I'm happy to be wrong if you have a solution)

Comment: Cool.  One last thing: can we always guarantee that a nickname will be shorter than the corresponding first name?  I worry about a case like `"Jimmy"` as a (diminutive form of the) nickname ("Jim") for `"James"`.

Comment: I don't think that the nickname will always be shorter than the corresponding first name, for exactly the reasons mention

Comment: Rather than selecting the longest `First` name present in `df` for that person, perhaps we should select the `First` name that has a match in the `Name` column of `nicknames`. That way, we are ensuring that the "default" is explicitly a first name, as explicitly stated in the mapping from first names to nicknames in `nicknames`.

Comment: That sounds reasonable, and should make things simple for the `Jane` case later in the workflow (her name is just maintained)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, if this solves your problem and is consistent to your desired output:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  left_join(nicknames, by=c("First" = "N1")) %>%
  mutate(real_name = coalesce(Name, First)) %>%
  group_by(Last, real_name) %>%
  mutate(id = n()) %>% 
  group_by(Last, First) %>%
  filter(id==max(id)) %>%
  select(-Name, -id)
```

returns

```r
# A tibble: 7 x 3
# Groups:   Last, First [6]
  First   Last  real_name
  <chr>   <chr> <chr>    
1 Steve   Jones Stephan  
2 Stephan Jones Stephan  
3 Steve   Jones Stephan  
4 Jane    Jones Jane     
5 Steve   Smith Steven   
6 Steven  Smith Steven   
7 Matt    Smith Matthew
```

Comment: Be careful and double check it on your real data. I'm not sure, if this approach works in a more general way...

Comment: In addtion: I didn't choose the longest name version but the version that doesn't have a nickname match to be the real name.